# SQLiteDatabase nested transaction and workaround

Tags: java, android, sqlite, transactions

**Edited:**
Yes, SQLite [doesn't support](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) nested transaction, but [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) declare that SQLiteDatabase does.
**Situation**
I've got a method containing transaction and I need to call this method from another transaction. 

 Additionally - both transactions work on the same set of records, but update different columns. 
**Problem**
It looks like results of my outer transactions are cancelled by inner one, still both are marked clean by setTransactionSuccessful() and finished by endTransaction() - I've checked this.
**Questions**

- Any idea why this may happen?
- Is there a recommended way to do such transactions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest transactions with the Android sqlite API, with [caveats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()):

> Transactions can be nested. When the outer transaction is ended all of the work done in that transaction and all of the nested transactions will be committed or rolled back. The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise they will be committed.

Another approach I've seen used with sqlite in general is to pass in a boolean parameter `isInTransaction` that tells the called method whether it should handle transactions on its own, or to let the caller handle transactions.

Comment: Thanks. [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) allow nested transaction, but it looks like my outer transaction results are somehow cancelled by inner one (each transaction deals with the same set of records, but updates different columns). /By the way, have you any idea how that may happen??/

Now I use conditional transaction (similar to your suggestion) and so I'll stick to it

Answer (score 10):

"Nested Android Transactions" do *not* use SQLites nested transaction/savepoint support.

Rather a nested Android transaction *suppresses* manifesting a SQLite transaction. The nested transaction *cannot* be rolled back itself, because it does not exist apart from the outside transaction. This can [be seen here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession.java#SQLiteSession.beginTransaction%28int%2Candroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteTransactionListener%2Cint%2Candroid.os.CancellationSignal%29) with the `mTransactionStack == null` guard.

The only way to *actually* support nested transactions - which SQLite *does* support, just not with BEGIN/COMMIT - is to to manually use the SAVEPOINT/RELEASE commands. Of course, designing the code to not rely on this will eliminate the extra manual management this requires.

(I would probably move all the transaction work out of the actual individual operations, leaving the management to the high-level caller; this works fairly well for a UoW pattern, but might not always be applicable.)

Answer (score 3):

For now I ended up with symmetrical method design (similar to laalto suggestion) which provides correct work. It's a workaround which explicitly "converts" nested transactions into single one.
Now I may call them separately or one from another (without side effects which I still don't understand).
Here it is:

```
    public void method1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    boolean doAsTransaction = !db.inTransaction();

    if (doAsTransaction)
        db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        // ...
        if (doAsTransaction)
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...

    } finally {
        // ...
        if (doAsTransaction)
            db.endTransaction();
    }
}


public void method2() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    boolean doAsTransaction = !db.inTransaction();

    if (doAsTransaction)
        db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        // ...
        method1();
        if (doAsTransaction)
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...

    } finally {
        // ...
        if (doAsTransaction)
            db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform nested transaction by using raw SQL for [savepoints](https://sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) in `execSQL()` in this way:

```
db.execSql("SAVEPOINT test"); // declare savepoint
// ... do some operations
db.execSql(";ROLLBACK TO test"); // rollback
db.execSql("RELEASE test"); // save changes
```

Semicolon in front of ROLLBACK is required, because without it Android database framework will try to call `endTransaction()`. See code of the methods `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession#executeSpecial` and `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession#execute` for details.

Comment: DatabaseUtils now supports savepoint rollback but warns that the semicolon is still required to work correctly on API levels 16-27.