# Android SQLite nested transactions in tests

Tags: android, sqlite, junit, transactions

In our application we have "mirror tables" - pairs of almost identical tables, and we need to test our app's logic so that handles writing in that mirror tables in proper way. Appears that we can test it on the database level only - we want to check that result of method's work was written in the database correctly. We thought that we can begin outer transaction in @BeforeClass method, perform some changes in nested transactions created and closed in test cases, so in every test case we will have the same basic data set loaded in the database and after some operations made by test case we'll just rollback nested transaction. And, of course, end outer transaction in @AfterClass method without marking it as clean so changes won't appear in the app's database.

It appears that it cannot be achieved because Android doesn't support nested transactions properly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106745/4606884).

Maybe there is the way to test this behaviour without affecting database? Or there is some workaround for nested transactions?

Thanks!

Comment: Android's database framework support nesting just fine. You did not read the other answer correctly.

Comment: Nested transactions aren't rollbacked as we expect. I've tested. Maybe I've missed something...

Comment: When any (outer or nested) transaction is not successful, the entire transaction is rolled back. What is wrong with that?

Comment: We wanted to rollback to the savepoint, I mean. And Android's database framework doesn't allow ROLLBACK TO operation, exception is thrown when we try to perform this operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android database framework](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) implements nested transactions, but only by suppressing any SQL statements for any inner transactions, any rolling back the outermost transaction if any (outer or nested) transaction is not successful.

Transactions and savepoints have different semantics. If you want to roll back to savepoints, you actually have to use the [savepoint statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html); in Android, this requires avoiding the framework's `beginTransaction()` etc. calls everywhere, and executing the savepoint SQL statements directly. In other words, you have to ensure that the tested code uses your own database framework.